# How to make a jar file from the files created by other tasks in gradle?

Tags: jar, gradle

In gradle, I need to make a jar by taskB from the files created after taskA has been execute. TaskA has no explicit output directory. Codes look like following:

```
task taskA << {
    //do sth during execution
}

task taskB(type:Jar) {
    //how should I fill the "from" method to achieve my goal
    from('a folder')
    archiveName = 'A.jar'
    destinationDir = file('destination')
}
```

Looking forward to your answer, thx!

*The following is added(updated) on 2015-8-2:*

Truly sorry for the inaccurate description before.

The answers showed till now I had already come up with them. But they can't achieve my goal.

Precisely speaking, "taskA" is a built-in task of one module in an android project, the "assembleDebug" task. And this module depends on some other modules in this same project. So when compile this module by executing an "assembleDebug"/"assembleRelease", other modules will also be compiled and are linked by making each other module compiled .class file to a jar in this module's folder.

And I need to pack all these modules' compiled **.class** files to **one** jar file, instead of packing jar files to jar file, in "taskB".

As you can see, there is not only one source folder and the folders are not an output of a task. So I dont' know if the method which uses "from task's output" form can meet my request.

Is there a valid solution?

Comment: What exactly does taskA generates? What type of task is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to combine the classes of dependencies and the classes of the current project into one JAR:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':depA')
}

task unzipAllClasses(type: Copy) {
    inputs.files(jar)
    inputs.files(configurations.compile)

    from configurations.compile.collect { zipTree(it) }, jar.outputs.files.collect { zipTree(it) }
    into new File(buildDir, "combined-classes")
}

task combinedJar(type: Jar) {
    from unzipAllClasses
    archiveName 'combined-with-deps.jar'
}

assemble.dependsOn combinedJar
```

You still have to make sure that the manifest that ends up in the combined JAR files contains what you want, and you have to get this published somehow without introducing duplicate classes on the classpath of the projects depending on this project.

Comment: Sorry for the inaccurate description before. I have updated the description. Please check it again if you have free time.

Answer (score 0):

If taskA has for example `'Copy'` type, then your job should be as simple as:

```
task taskA(type: Copy) {
  // do sth
}

task taskB(type: Jar) {
  from taskA
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the inaccurate description before. I have updated the description. Please check it again if you have free time.